# Getting slightly different input in each data fetch operation

Tags: python, io, tensorflow

I am following the [cifar10 tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10) and fetch my data using [inputs()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py#L197) function called by [cifar10.inputs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10.py#L163). My code is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cifar10

# Get images and labels
images, labels = cifar10.inputs(eval_data='test')

# Start running operations on the Graph.
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

# Start the queue runners.
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)

img, lab = sess.run([images, labels])
print(lab)
```

To test this, I run the code with batch size 10 and print the **labels** of the first batch. I expect the same output each time I execute this code, because **shuffle=False** in the [inputs()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py#L197) function. However, I observe slightly different labels in each execution, for example outputs from three consecutive executions are:

```
run-1: [0 1 2 2 1 1 1 9 8 8]
run-2: [1 2 2 0 1 1 1 9 8 8]
run-3: [0 2 2 1 1 1 1 9 8 8]
```

I would like to know:

1. Why I am getting different labels although shuffle is off? and
2. What should I do to obtain the same labels at each execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The queue runners you are starting there are multiple threads loading data from disk and adding it to the queue. [There are 16 of them by default](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py#L117).

The queue itself is thread-safe, but there is nothing enforcing order.

So even though you're not using the shuffling queue, the race-condition between the threads to fetch and insert the items randomizes the order slightly.

The easiest way to make it completely repeatable is to only use 1 thread to fetch items. This will probably be slow.

Comment: Hi @mdaoust, very helpful answer to clarify the question. One more problem. I have labels like: [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...]. While fetching data I observe that it doesn't start from first index, e.g., with batch size 5 i get [0 0 0 1 1]. Can you please tell me why?

It uses [tf.train.batch()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py#L126) function.

Comment: Summary writers consume data from queue so turn of summary threads to see all data